# How do I run the application download from the site files

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I have got source code from the site and want to run that small application.

What are the steps and what should I do to run that application?

I have shown the attachment pics showing the files of that application that are:

```
MRG.Controls.UI
MRG.WinForm.Test
MRG.Controls.sln
MRG.Controls.suo
```

now the folder `MRG.Controls.UI` have the following files,

```
Properties
LoadingCircle.cs
LoadingCircle.Designer.cs
LoadingCircleToolStripMenuItem.cs
MRG.Controls.UI.csproj
```

and the folder `MRG.WinForm.Test` have the following ones:

```
Properties
frmMain.cs
frmMain.Designer.cs
frmMain.resx
MRG.WinForm.Test.csproj
MRG.WinForm.Test.csproj.user
Program.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

If visual studio is installed double click on MRG.Controls.sln file

then press F5 key or Debug->Start debugging from menu item in visual studio application

Comment: Chilaka Umesh,Oscar Mederos thanks for you reply i will try it then let you know

Answer (score 1):

You need to double-click on the `MRG.Controls.sln` file which will then open it in Visual Studio.  If you don't have the right version of VS.Net installed, you will need to install that, of course.

Once loaded, ensure that the top-level node in Solution Explorer is selected and then press F5.

Comment: it is giving error "sure that the for the project .cspro is installed" i have installed VS2008 with c#

Comment: it is giving error hope that for the project .cspro is intalled??